# How can i make the shoulder joint deform smoothly?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, topology

When i deform it, this is the result:

[image]

I've tried with shape keys to "fix" it, but it doesn't solve anything (or maybe im just a noob).

I believe that is because the topology of the character is not good, maybe.

The point is that i want something like this
[image]

So, a good topology will solve the thing or... there's something more i should do for a good deformation of the shoulders (and any joint in general)?

Comment: yes your topology seems bad and uselessly complicated, could you please share your file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6452" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6452/)

Comment: yes as I say I think your topology is bad and uselessly complicated, but the character is very nice, so you should consider retopologize it completely, it should not be too complicated, but it would be hard to sum it up here

Comment: So... if i retopologize it and achieve the "correct" topology, my problem will be gone and the deformation will be like in the Gif?

Comment: well at least it will help

Comment: The gif does the movement utilizing the collar bone and chest+pyramid muscles, the actual upper arms angle is a lot less extreme than in your example. The deltoid won't even deform to 90° in reality.

Comment: I guess it will not completely solve your problem if you have bad topology, but maybe a _Smooth Corrective Modifier_ placed after the _Armature Modifier_ might be a bit helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the shoulder joint (the ball connecting shoulder to upper arm bones) forward and inward a bit. It's a common tendency to put the "ball" of the joint where the outer limits of the acromion... joint is a bit closer. https://www.assh.org/handcare/blog/anatomy-101-shoulder-bones When the joint is too far out it causes "crunching" near the armpit like you have pictured.

Next up, when painting weights, use 100% weight from the chest bone much higher than you'd expect. At the "center" of the armpit crease it'll be something like 80% - 90% chest bone, then blend to 100% arm over two or three iso lines.

Don't get discouraged because what you're doing is really hard but you're not too far away from getting there!

Answer (score 0):

You can go with bad topology, IMO. I’ve answered a similar problem here:
[Realistic Rigging with real skeleton?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98976/realistic-rigging-with-real-skeleton/123351#123351)
Basically, you need a shape key for every pose of the arm. Then blend between 2 shape keys, other then the Basis.

*If you have questions, I’d be glad to answer them.*